# Que no se puedan repetir valores en 2 columnas de diferentes tablas

Tags: sql

Verán, tengo este par de tablas. Una de ella es de información sobre clientes de una tienda y la otra es la información de los empleados de dicha tienda:

```
create table cliente(
  id serial primary key,
  nombre varchar,
  dni integer,
  fecha_registro date
);

create table empleado(
  id serial primary key,
  nombre varchar,
  fecha_nacimiento date,
  dni integer,
  ciudad_natal varchar,
  fecha_contratacion date
);
```

Ambas tablas poseen una columna llamada "dni", que obtiene el DNI del empleado. Pues lo que quiero es montar un valor único en ambas tablas.
Es decir, si, por ejemplo, tengo un cliente con id 345, no podre darle a un empleado un id de 345, y viceversa.
¿Como se logra eso? He buscado información por internet y no encuentro nada.

Comment: pregunta al final un empleado no es un cliente? y unir empleados con clientes no deberia ser lo mas optimo, recomendaria  unir las tablas y asignar un columna `tipo` donde podrias ser `0,1`  donde 0 es cliente y 1 es empleado. un crear un triger de insert que validare los si el `dni` del cliente existe en `empleados` ya que hasta donde se los `dni` son unicos!

Comment: No hay una forma directa de hacerlo. Tendrías dos alternativas principales, una es crear un trigger en ambas tablas para revisar cada registro que se ingrese, y la segunda sería crear una vista que una ambas tablas y agregarle un índice único a esa tabla

Comment: No, la idea es que Cliente y Empleado son tablas totalmente independientes. Y lo que he hecho es lo que dice @Lamak, crearme un sistema mediante Javascript que comprueba cada vez que cree una fila para las tablas si hay alguna coincidencia en los DNI.